# using a php function inside a php variable

Tags: php

I have created this function

```
function AdminNameLookup ($sequence) {
        global $pdo_conn, $conn, $usertype_user, $usertype_admin, $usertype_accounts, $usertype_support;

        $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from admin where sequence = :sequence ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $sequence));
    $result=$stmt->fetch();
```

but i want to be able to display different results when calling the function, can i do something like:

```
$run_function = AdminNameLookup('123');

echo $run_function["TableColumn"]
```

Comment: Mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: OK I think you're saying you want to store the results of the function in a variable? Yes, that's definitely possible.

Comment: Forget MySQLi, he's using PDO variables. Use this instead: http://us2.php.net/PDO

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox whats the best way to store the results?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. What you've written will save the first row in your result to `$run_function`. Then you can access elements of that row through `$run_function[...]`.

Comment: if possible, i want to be able to display all table columns by just putting the column name when calling the function

Comment: is it possible that way ?

Comment: how can i make all rows display too?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Your function AdminNameLookup returns an array - a copy of the row.  That should work.

Comment: do you have an example please

Comment: i tried this as my function: function AdminUserSessionID($user_sequence) {
  global $pdo_conn, $conn, $usertype_user, $usertype_admin, $usertype_accounts, $usertype_support;
  $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from admin where sequence = :sequence ");
  $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $user_sequence));
  $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $results=array();
  foreach($records as $records2) {
   $defaultOptions["forename"] = $records2["forename"];
  }
  return $results = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);
 }

Comment: and calling it here: $test = AdminUserSessionID($_SESSION["lifeline.integra-uk.net"]["sequence"]);
echo $test["forename"]; - but that didn't show anything

Comment: Your code isn't formatted to read, and your question has migrated well off the original.  You should trap for a PDO error first.  Once you establish that's working check your array_merge: the $options array is neither set or declared global.